# SQL Server Management change column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know sql but I when i tried few things to change a column name in sql entreprise edition 2012 (in sql server management studio) it doesn't work
what i tried:

```
alter table Table_name rename column oldName to newName;
Update Table_name set oldName= newName;
```

with a couple similar things also but no result always an error about rename not recognized etc..

Comment: You can also just right click on the column directly and select "Rename".  You won't have to run anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `sp_rename` to rename your column

```
EXEC sp_rename 'Sales.SalesTerritory.TerritoryID', 'TerrID', 'COLUMN';
```

**http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/26/sql-server-how-to-rename-a-column-name-or-table-name/**
**https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx**

Comment: [SQL Authority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/26/sql-server-how-to-rename-a-column-name-or-table-name/) Also has a good article on how to rename the column/table.

Comment: thanks a lot found it at the same time you posted xD